# Are German "Tier" (animal) and Latin "fera" (wild animal) related?

Tags: etymology

Are German "Tier" (animal) and Latin "fera" (wild animal) related? Both look like they might come from an Indo-European root such as *d<sup>h</sup>eh<sub>1</sub>r, as PIE *d<sup>h</sup> changes to 't' in German and to 'f' in Latin.

Comment: Have you checked the etymologies of both words from Wiktionary or some other source? A quick search would pretty easily give a starting point for others to build on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Latin *fera* (*ferus*, *ferōx*, &c.) is typically reconstructed as deriving from the root **ǵʰu̯e(h₁)r-*, making it cognate to Greek θήρ 'wild animal' and its derivatives (with regular development of labiovelar/velar+labial to dental before a front vowel). Outside of Latin and Greek cognates are confined to Balto-Slavic (Lithuanian *žvėrìs*, Russian зверь, &c.—forms that require a palatovelar) and Tocharian (Tocharian B *śerwe* 'hunter').

German *Tier* (English *deer*, Icelandic *dýr*, &c.) cannot be related: the Gothic cognate  *dius* and the *ʀ* in Old East Norse *diūʀ* prove the *r* must be a result of rhotacism, and the PIE root is taken to be **dʰeu̯s-* 'breath, soul' (cf. Russian душа 'soul', Latvian *dvēsele* 'soul').
It has occasionally been suggested Latin *bēstia* and *bēlua* derive from this same root with metathesis (not actually schwebeablaut) as **dʰu̯es-* with the same evolution of Old Latin *dw* to *b* as seen in *bonus*, *bellum*, and *bis*, but PIE **dʰu̯-* should yield Latin *f-* at the start of a word, not *dw-* (as in *forum* < PIE **dʰu̯orom*). It's also possible *furō* 'to rage' is from this root (cf. Old English *dēor* 'wild, bold' next to *dēor* 'wild animal'), but the etymology is disputed.

Of course, Latin did also undergo rhotacism of [z], so could *fera* derive from PIE **dʰu̯es-eh₂* and be an exact cognate for Germanic *deuzą < **dʰeu̯s-o-m* apart from the gender and the unexplained metathesis? Formally, yes, and we happen not to have Old Latin (pre-rhotacism) or other Italic attestations to disprove it. Random metathesis is a pretty big thing to hand-wave when an alternative etymology exists, though.

Comment: Eng. *bear* may also be cognate with *ferus*, if one accepts the controversial change PIE *gʷʰ-/*ǵʰw- > PGm. *b-.